# How to save the changes made to row in the listview?

Tags: android

What my code does is add,delete and edit operations.On click of add button the name gets added to the list and on delete the particular row gets deleted.similarly,on click of edit button a dialog box will be prompted in which edit operation has to be performed then on click of save,the data edited should be updated in that particular row.

Problem i'm facing is on click of save button the app is getting crashed.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView userList;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    Button addButton;
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();
    EditText editText;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * add item in arraylist
         */
        userArray.add(new User("a"));
        userArray.add(new User("b"));
        userArray.add(new User("c"));
        userArray.add(new User("d"));
        userArray.add(new User("e"));
        userArray.add(new User("f"));
        userArray.add(new User("g"));
        final Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_data);

        /**
         * set item into adapter
         */
        userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_view_layout,
                userArray);

        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        /**
         * on click of add button(add data to arraylist)
         */
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                userArray.add(new User(editText.getText().toString()));
                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        /**
         * get on item click listener
         */
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Name Clicked:" +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });}}
```

**UserCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<User> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.addButton =(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
            holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
            holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        User user = data.get(position);

        holder.textName.setText(user.getName());

        /**
         * prompt dialog on click of edit button
         */

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("EDIT NAME");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Name");

                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alertDialog.setView(input);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(context,srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });


                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }

        });
            /**
             * Delete's a name from the list
             */
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                data.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return row;

    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        Button btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        Button addButton;}}
```

error is at userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

plz help me out,Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please post the LogCat also...

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace ?
Which line is causing your app to crash ?

Comment: you should call userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResume of your activity. When you are calling notifyDataSetChanged in alert dialog, the actual activity is not active or is in paused state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your Adapter as below

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> data;//<--------changed
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<User> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
       userAdapter = this;//<--------changed
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.addButton =(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
            holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
            holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        User user = data.get(position);

        holder.textName.setText(user.getName());

        /**
         * prompt dialog on click of edit button
         */

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("EDIT NAME");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Name");

                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alertDialog.setView(input);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(context,srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     data.get(position).setName(srt);//<--------changed
                        notifyDataSetChanged();//<--------changed

                    }
                });


                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }

        });
            /**
             * Delete's a name from the list
             */
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                data.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return row;

    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        Button btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        Button addButton;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting null pointer exception..

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter; // b'coz of this line
```

it is uninitialized/null variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think sourabh bans is right about the NullPointerException. Try this:

```
public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                         ArrayList<User> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

    // add this line
    userAdapter = this;

}
```

Comment: yup its working fine now.but the data is not getting altered

Comment: cuz you are not setting data back to list.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
LayoutInflater
```

in getView

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu, null);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.addButton =(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
        holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    User user = data.get(position);

    holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
```